# Join a JSON Object and Array in DataWeave

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule4

I have 2 JSON structures one is an object the other one is an array though it will always have either no objects or just 1 JSON object.

The First JSON object is like:

```
var var1={
  "orgID": "1234",
  "apiID": 100,
  "envID": "45678",
  "apiName": "logging-system-api",
  "exchangeAsset": "Logging System API"
}
```

the JSON array looks like:

```
var var2=[{
    "apiID": 100,
    "policyName1": "client-id-enforcement",
    "policyName2": null,
    "policyName3": null,
    "policyName4": null,
    "policyName5": null,
    "policyName6": null
  }]
```

or it could be

```
var var2=[]
```

the desired output always is a JSON Object like:

```
{
  "orgID": "1234",
  "apiID": 100,
  "envID": "45678",
  "apiName": "logging-system-api",
  "exchangeAsset": "Logging System API"
  "policyName1": "client-id-enforcement",
  "policyName2": null,
  "policyName3": null,
  "policyName4": null,
  "policyName5": null,
  "policyName6": null
}
```

Note: first JSON structure is an object second JSON structure is an array though it has 0 or 1 element always. policyName1 to policyName6 always needs to be in the output irrespective of whether the second JSON array contains something or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decomposing the problem into its parts, I used a variable with the default values for policyNameX that is concatenated to `var1` to avoid missing them. I used `reduce()` on the array to concatenate all items into an object, then merged both results into a single object using `dw::core::Objects::mergeWith()`.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import mergeWith from dw::core::Objects

var var1={
  "orgID": "1234",
  "apiID": 100,
  "envID": "45678",
  "apiName": "logging-system-api",
  "exchangeAsset": "Logging System API"
}

var var2=[{
    "apiID": 100,
    "policyName1": "client-id-enforcement",
    "policyName2": null,
    "policyName3": null,
    "policyName4": null,
    "policyName5": null,
    "policyName6": null
  }]

var defaultPolicies={
    "policyName1": null,
    "policyName2": null,
    "policyName3": null,
    "policyName4": null,
    "policyName5": null,
    "policyName6": null
}  
---
(var1 ++ defaultPolicies) mergeWith(var2 reduce ((item, acc = {}) -> acc ++ item))
```

Output:

```json
{
  "orgID": "1234",
  "envID": "45678",
  "apiName": "logging-system-api",
  "exchangeAsset": "Logging System API",
  "apiID": 100,
  "policyName1": "client-id-enforcement",
  "policyName2": null,
  "policyName3": null,
  "policyName4": null,
  "policyName5": null,
  "policyName6": null
}
```

Comment: If there are more than one elements in the array you can use mergeWith() instead of concatenation in the reduce.

Answer (score 3):

This is an alternative using object factory to @aled excelent solution

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Objects
var var1={
  "orgID": "1234",
  "apiID": 100,
  "envID": "45678",
  "apiName": "logging-system-api",
  "exchangeAsset": "Logging System API"
}

var defaultPolicies={
    "policyName1": null,
    "policyName2": null,
    "policyName3": null,
    "policyName4": null,
    "policyName5": null,
    "policyName6": null
}  

var var2=[{
    "apiID": 100,
    "policyName1": "client-id-enforcement",
    "policyName2": null,
    "policyName3": null,
    "policyName4": null,
    "policyName5": null,
    "policyName6": null
  }]
---
{
    (var1),
    (defaultPolicies)
} mergeWith {(var2)}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another variation using [join](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-arrays-functions-join)

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays
var var1={
  "orgID": "1234",
  "apiID": 100,
  "envID": "45678",
  "apiName": "logging-system-api",
  "exchangeAsset": "Logging System API"
}


var defaultPolicies=[{
    "policyName1": null,
    "policyName2": null,
    "policyName3": null,
    "policyName4": null,
    "policyName5": null,
    "policyName6": null
}]


var var1arr = ([] + var1)

var var2=[{
    "apiID": 100,
    "policyName1": "client-id-enforcement",
    "policyName2": null,
    "policyName3": null,
    "policyName4": null,
    "policyName5": null,
    "policyName6": null
  }]

var var22 = []

var joinvars = if( sizeOf(var2) != 0) join(var1arr, var2, (var1arr) -> var1arr."apiID", (var2) -> var2."apiID") else join(var1arr, defaultPolicies, (var1arr) -> "", (defaultPolicies) -> "")

---

joinvars.l[0] ++ (joinvars.r[0] - "apiID")
```

Answer (score 0):

Below script will also help you.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays
var var1={
  "orgID": "1234",
  "apiID": 100,
  "envID": "45678",
  "apiName": "logging-system-api",
  "exchangeAsset": "Logging System API"
}


var var2=[{
    "apiID": 100,
    "policyName1": "client-id-enforcement",
    "policyName2": null,
    "policyName3": null,
    "policyName4": null,
    "policyName5": null,
    "policyName6": null
  }]
var varJoin = join([var1],var2, (var1) -> var1.apiID, (var2) -> var2.apiID)
---
{(varJoin.l ++ varJoin.r)} distinctBy $$
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).